# javascript cannot surpass xmlhttprequest error using ajax/JS/mysql/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

we have on the client side running this javascript code:

```
var src;
var y = document.getElementById('trigger-image-toll-id');
function addListener() {
    src = $('#nice_image').attr("src");
    alert(src);
}
y.click();
setTimeout(function(){
addListener()
}, 5000);

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://www.orc23.com/insert.php",
    data: { theurl: src, asker: "test", solution53: "" }
})
    .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Remote server side we have this php file I am trying to use to insert data into mysql DB:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');


$con =
mysqli_connect("orc23com.coooscowmysql.com","jim","jim123","coolbeans");
//$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cl30-ssndb");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

mysqli_select_db($con, "coolbeans");

$sql="INSERT INTO requests (theurl, asker, solution53)
VALUES
('$_POST[theurl]','$_POST[asker]','$_POST[solution53]')";

if (! mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con)
?>

<a href="index.php">Back To Home Page Click Here</a>
```

I've already tried to disable web security with Chrome option for my Chrome Browser but still getting this error here:

> xmlhttprequest cannot load REMOTE WEBSITE HERE WITH A "insert.php"  . response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource. origin 'adifferentwebsite' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: What is the question exactly? How to get around CORS? set the CORS headers.

Comment: essentially yes, setting CORS headers and also how to get around CORS , basically whatever will be easiest to do, I've tried using Chrome -disable-web-security --user-data-dir , but doesn't help .... whatever it takes to get past this preflight request check .... please , and thanks in advance !

Comment: One option, although not particularly elegant, would be to create a local PHP file that basically acts as a proxy. Make an ajax request to your local PHP file which then makes a cURL request to the remote file and pushes back the response.